# unfortunately the app has stopped when i am debugging if I cast PaintDrawable to Drawable

Tags: java, android

I'm studying and trying to make some Android application with android studio. But I found something that I can't understand.

If I write the sentence below, there is no problem:

> TextView vm = new TextView(this);
>
> Drawable pnt = vm.getBackground();

but, if I write a sentence like below, where I cast `PaintDrawable` to the righthand, and build this app and install apk to my device, app doesn't work showing message "Unfortunately, the app has stopped".

> TextView vm = new TextView(this);
>
> PaintDrawable pnt = (PaintDrawable) vm.getBackground();

Answer (score 0):

TextView::getBackground [returns a Drawable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.0mBGDrawable), not necessarily a PaintDrawable.

You are attempting to downcast to PaintDrawable without checking whether you can do so.  Try this:

```
TextView vm = new TextView(this);

if (vm.getBackground() instanceof PainDrawable) {
    PaintDrawable pnt = (PaintDrawable) vm.getBackground();
    // ...
}
else {
    Log.d("SomeTag", vm.getBackground().getClass());
}
```